# Utilizar diccionarios de un archivo de texto

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo de texto que contiene muchísimas líneas de información que están estructuradas en diccionarios sin nombres y cada una esta comentada. Adjunto un ejemplo ilustrativo:

```
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":781,"Andalucía":202,"Canarias":330}} #Comentario1
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":15,"Andalucía":82,"Canarias":37}} #Comentario2
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":0.0515,"Andalucía":802,"Canarias":0.137}} #Comentario3
```

A mí lo que me gustaría es acceder, por ejemplo a los valores que toma Andalucía, que sería 202,82,802 para poder trabajar con ellos, lo que pasa es que no sé como de ese archivo de texto trabajar con esos diccionarios ya que a parte de que no sé como trabajar con esos diccionarios pues tampoco tienen nombre. ¿Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes una versión rápida y funcional.
Pienso que el script es adecuado a tu nivel. Tu mismo podrás ampliarlo, hay muchas cosas que mejorar, pero por eso también tienes que aportar mas información.

#### fichero data.txt

```
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":781,"Andalucía":202,"Canarias":330}} #Comentario1
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":15,"Andalucía":82,"Canarias":37}} #Comentario2
{"País":"España","Comunidades":{"Madrid":0.0515,"Andalucía":802,"Canarias":0.137}} #Comentario3
```

#### script python3

```py
import ast

datos = []
with open('data.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        to_dict = ast.literal_eval(line)
        datos.append(to_dict)

for i in datos:
    print(i.get('Comunidades',{}).get('Andalucía',{}))
```

Ambos ficheros deben estar al mismo directorio

Comment: Primero que nada, muchas gracias por responder. Utilizando el ejemplo ilustrativo que di y tu código no me toma los datos. Al compilar el código me muestra tres llaves vacías. Le daré una vuelta para ver si consigo que funcione del todo y luego trasladarlo a mi problema

Comment: Pues a mi me funciona de lujo.  Puedes editar añadiendo unas cuantas linas mas de los datos origen?

Comment: He añadido varias líneas más al archivo de texto en el que tengo el ejemplo y me sucede lo mismo, me genera tantas llaves vacías como líneas. Y el código no lo he modificado. Intentaré buscar la solución utilizando tu código como apoyo, gracias

Comment: Por añadir, cuando solo utilizo  print(i.get('Comunidades',{})) sí me recoge bien las comunidades, el problema es cuando añado .get('Andalucía',{}) para solo tomar los datos de Andalucía

Comment: No será el acento?. Si te fijas obtenemos los datos via .get() del dictionario. Eso lo he hecho para que si en una lina no esta esa llave, no pete el programa.

Comment: ¡Eres genial! jajaja ¡era eso! ¡qué fallo tan tonto! ¡Muchas gracias! ¿Esos datos se pueden almacenar en una lista? Para poder trabajar con ellos?

Comment: Pues claro, la lista es datos. Ya estan en una lista. Puedes iterar encima de ellos...

Comment: Una pregunta. Al realizar el código, lo que hago es almacenar esos diccionarios en una lista. Pero habría alguna forma de que esos diccionarios del archivo de texto, en python vuelvan a ser diccionarios? es decir, que no esten dentro de una lista?

Comment: No, son 3 diccionarios, o los guardas por separado, o los pones juntitos en una lista. En tu caso, no puedes hacer 3 diccionarios a 1, a nose que te inventes keys para ello.... por ejemplo {1: {'Pais': España',...},2:{'Pais:'Esp'...}},

Comment: Vale, gracias. Muy amable^^